# Python - Split String with Parenthesis based off a Pattern

Tags: python, string, split

I have a problem in python where I have a pattern, that can repeat anywhere from 1 to XXX times.

The pattern is I have a string of format

Author (Affiliation) Author (Affiliation) etc etc etc as many authors/affiliations that there are.

What is the best way in Python to go about splitting a string up like this when you dont know if you'll have 1 instance of Author (Affiliation) or 100?

EDIT - Viktor Leis* (Technische Universität München) Alfons Kemper (Technische Universität München) Thomas Neumann (Technische Universität München, Germany)

That is a sample string I am working with.  I have tried re.split / re.findall and am having no luck. I'm assuming I am doing something with regex's wrong.

EDIT 2 - '\w+{1,3}(\w{1,10})'  Is the pattern I was attempting to use.

My logic was a name is 1-3 words, then (.  Then an affiliation is between 1-10 words, and a closing ).

Comment: use re.findall https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a sample. Looks like you are wanting to match text with no ) or ( and the text in between ( and ). Below is one way to do it assuming it is exactly like above.

```
import re
text = r'Viktor Leis* (Technische Universitt Mnchen) Alfons Kemper (Technische Universitt Mnchen) Thomas Neumann (Technische Universitt Mnchen, Germany)'
pattern = '[^\(\)]* \([^\(]+\)'
result = re.findall(pattern,s)
print result
```

**output:**

```
['Viktor Leis* (Technische Universitt Mnchen)', ' Alfons Kemper (Technische Universitt Mnchen)', ' Thomas Neumann (Technische Universitt Mnchen, Germany)']
```

You may want to removing leading and trailing spaces using strip.

Answer (score 0):

This is the first thing that comes to mind

```
import re
s = 'Bob (ABC) Steve (XYZ) Mike (ALPHA)'
pattern = '\w+ \(\w+\)'

>>> re.findall(pattern,s)
['Bob (ABC)', 'Steve (XYZ)', 'Mike (ALPHA)']
```

Comment: Hey sir!

Thanks for the suggestion! I had thought the same thing originally with using re.  My expression was similar. I actually tried re.split in my guess, but to no avail. I keep getting empty sets with yours.  Perhaps if I include a sample line it would work better? 

Viktor Leis* (Technische Universität München) Alfons Kemper (Technische Universität München) Thomas Neumann (Technische Universität München, Germany)

Is one of the many strings I am trying to split apart using that pattern.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this:

```
thing="Author1 (Affiliation) Author2 (Affiliation) Author3 (Affiliation)"
s=thing.split(') ')

list=[]
for i in s:
    if not i.endswith(')'):
        list.append(i+')')
    else:
        list.append(i)
```

Comment: Hello! Thanks. This may have to be what I do - it's much nicer than trying to figure out the regular expression issues I am having.